# DatagramSocket fails on Android with 'Try Again'

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

I am trying to send `DatagramPackets` (UDP) in my Android application:

```
//create a byte to receive data
mClientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
byte[] receiveData = new byte[MAX_RECEIVE_DATA_SIZE_BYTES];
DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
        receiveData.length);

// Set a receive timeout
mClientSocket.setSoTimeout(timeout);

// receive the packet
mClientSocket.receive(receivePacket);

return new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0,
        receivePacket.getLength());
```

I get the following error:

> Try again

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to send the UDP you'd need something similar to:

Server:

```
String  messageStr="Hello Android!";
int server_port = 12345;
DatagramSocket  s = new DatagramSocket ();
InetAddress  local = InetAddress .getByName("192.168.1.102");
int msg_length=messageStr.length();
byte[] message = messageStr.getBytes();
DatagramPacket  p = new DatagramPacket (message, msg_length,local,server_port);
s.send(p);
```

Client:

```
String  text;
int server_port = 12345;
byte[] message = new byte[1500];
DatagramPacket  p = new DatagramPacket (message, message.length);
DatagramSocket  s = new DatagramSocket (server_port);
s.receive(p);
text = new String (message, 0, p.getLength());
Log.d("Udp tutorial","message:" + text);
s.close();
```

**References:**

- [Simple UDP communication example](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-udp-communication-example)

Comment: Hello David. In client side I have  some controller in network. I tested signal via other program (Serial&Net tools). but didn'n send UDP from my app. `catch (Exception e)
        {
            android.util.Log.w("UDP", "Catched here 4");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`  this code works

Comment: Help please. which problems may be. I'm beginner on android